# Oracle - ignoring constraint failures

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a 'staff' table with many rows, and I would like to remove unused rows from this table (all the staff who were never referenced by any other table.)

There are constraints in place such that it is not possible to delete rows from the staff table if they are being referenced elsewhere.  Because of this I was hoping I could just `DELETE FROM STAFF` which would remove the unreferenced rows and leave the others.

Unfortunately Oracle considers this an error, so as soon as it encounters a row that is referenced externally the whole query fails with a constraint violation.

Is there some way I can tell Oracle to just ignore the constraint violation, leave the record as is and move on to the next one?

Comment: Instead, I'd suggest that you structure your delete statement to only delete the STAFF records that you know aren't referenced by another table...  If you post your table definitions, we could help you make that query...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: Unfortunately this is for an enterprise (read: huge, messy and badly documented) system, and part of the problem is that I don't know which tables reference staff.  So this question is really about how I can avoid learning more of the schema than I really want to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DML error logging:

```
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'STAFF'
    ,err_log_table_name => 'STAFF_ERRORS');

delete from STAFF
log errors into STAFF_ERRORS('Is referenced') reject limit 999999999;
```

Then optionally delete, truncate, or drop the table STAFF_ERRORS.

Comment: Hello, I tried this approach but I'm still getting the error from oracle. Any advise?

Comment: @Kohakukun Check these [restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55101).

Answer (score 1):

You can use PLSQL:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT id FROM STAFF) LOOP
    begin
       delete STAFF where id = r.id;
    exception
       when others then
          null;
    end;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

But it might take some time to complete ...

Comment: You can probably speed this up with ROWID, BULK COLLECT, and FORALL.